# Using spark to handle 20 GB CSV file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a 20 GB CSV file. It can fit into memory (128 GB memory available), do I get a advantage  in terms of performance to use Spark to analyze it?

Answer (score 0):

if it can fit in your RAM you  won't get any noticeable advantage by using Spark , if you want you can try to use Dask for parallel computing in place of pandas.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get much improvement, if there's any, from using Spark in this case.

From my understanding, you can achieve great improvement from using Spark in cases which data does not fit on 1 single machine and it helps you make use of processing power of multiple machines in your cluster.

So in this case, you should try making use of parallel processing instead of using Spark.